# What is probability, that later pull out two cards are aces?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

From package of 32 cards I randomly pull out 1 card and then another 2 cards. What is probability, that later pulled out two cards are aces? (There are four aces)

I have came to the solution $\frac{15}{1240}\cdot100\doteq1.21\%$, but in the student's book the result is $\frac{15}{124}\%\doteq0.121\%$ which is exactly tenth of my result.

**Student's book solution:**
$$C_1(4, 2)={4\choose 2}=\frac{4!}{2!(4-2)!}=6$$
$$C_2(32, 3)={32\choose 3}=\frac{32!}{3!(32-3)!}=4960$$
$$p=100\cdot\frac{C_1(4, 2)}{C_2(32, 3)}=100\cdot\frac{6}{4960}=\frac{15}{124}=0.121\%$$

**My solution:**
$O$ - Other card than ace
$A$ - Ace

There are two combinations when last two cards are aces:
1.) $O$ $A$ $A$
Probability of this combination is
$$\frac{28}{32}\cdot\frac{4}{31}\cdot\frac{3}{30}=\frac{14}{1240}$$
2.) $A$ $A$ $A$
Probability of this combination is
$$\frac{4}{32}\cdot\frac{3}{31}\cdot\frac{2}{30}=\frac{1}{1240}$$
So probability is
$$p=100\cdot(\frac{14}{1240}+\frac{1}{1240})=100\cdot\frac{15}{1240}\doteq1.21\%$$

So, my question is: **which result is correct/isn't correct and why/why not?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just ignore the first card pulled as long as you don't look at it.  The chance of two aces is then $\frac 4{32} \cdot \frac 3{31}=\frac 3{248}=\frac {15}{1240}$.  The book has ignored all the choices for the first card, but when it takes $32 \choose 3$ as the probability space it has to consider that.